# Is there a specific hook that is executed on git submodule update?

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I'd like to ask if there is a possible way that a hook is executed on git submodule update; possibly like a post-update hook? thanks! :)

I like to execute a script (for now it just contains echo msg) that is executed every time git submodule update is run.

I have tried post-update hook but it seems that submodule update does not trigger this. I'd appreciate help. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A post-update, like a post-receive hook, would be a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks).
So it is expected to *not* work locally (client side)

So there is no specific hook for a `git submodule update`, which means you would need to script the `git` command itself in a wrapper, to detect the `submodule` argument, and chain that command with your echos.

Another convoluted approach is described in "[**`git-submodule` with git-hooks — A way to scalable repositories**](https://medium.com/@dopeddude/git-submodule-with-git-hooks-for-scalable-repos-50924f969937)" from [**Ashwini Kumar**](https://twitter.com/dopeddude), where a `pre-commit` hook is trigger by a `git commit` (done after a `git submodule update`), which will look at the diff introduced by said commit.
If the diff involves submodules, then it proceeds with additional commands.

Answer (score 2):

Create an alias:

```
git config alias.sup !"git submodule update; my-post-sup-hook"
```

and always update submodules using the alias:

```
git sup
```